# How to efficiently get total likes for every timeline post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like an efficient way to get total likes for every post for a given facebook page. To get the total shares, I can submit the following request to the API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page>/posts?fields=shares
```

and get back a list of total number of shares per post. However, when I try to do the same with likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page>/posts?fields=likes
```

I get a list of users who have liked that post, capped at 25. To get the total number of likes I would have to traverse the list for each post, which would be rather impractical. Is there any way to get the information in the same format as for shares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above can be accomplished with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page>/posts?fields=likes.summary(true)
```

Which will still fetch pages of people who liked the post but will also have an additional summary field showing the total count.